# Is it possible set image behind of cell value with EP Plus?

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, epplus

Does EP Plus support write text on image or set image to behind the cell value?

Answer (score 1):

MS Excel does not support placing images behind the cell value, but you can do one of the following tricks:

1. Place an **image** and a **text box** over the image
2. Add a **rectangle shape with picture fill** and set a level of **transparency** (not sure if EPPlus support image fill)